# Rows Sorting properly but not items in those rows?

Tags: php, sql

```
$sql = "SELECT counter, title FROM items WHERE ORDER BY counter DESC LIMIT 100";
$result = $conn->query($sql);              

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$count = $row['counter'];
$i++; 

if($i==1){
echo '<div class="row">';
}

echo '<div class="col-sm-3">';
echo '<p><a href="index.php>'.$row[$title].'<br  />'.$count.'</a></p>';
echo '</div>';

if($i==4){
echo '</div>';
$i=0;
}
}
}
```

The code above displays 3 items per row using bootstrap.

The problem I am have is that the ROWS are sorting properly, BUT the 3 items in each row are NOT sorting properly,(by counter DESC).

As an example, I am getting:

```
<p>1500 -- 1345 -- 1675</p>
<p>1233 -- 1267 -- 1331</p>
<p>1232 -- 1209 -- 1222</p>
```

As you can see, ALL the items in row 1 are DESC when compared to rows 2 and 3, but the individual items in row one are not sorting properly.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try Using below code

```
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT counter, title FROM items WHERE ORDER BY counter DESC LIMIT 100";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);


    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $i++; 

    if($i==1){
    echo '<div class="row">';
    }

    echo '<div class="col-sm-3">';
    echo '<p><a href="index.php>'.$row['title'].'<br  />'.$row['counter'].'</p>';
    echo '</div>';

    if($i==4){
    echo '</div>';
    $i=0;
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: You are access `title and counter` without using `$row`

Comment: Sorry - I corrected the code  - relook at the original post. (I made a few errors in an attempt to trim it down).. I actual have the $row and it is not working properly

Comment: Can you print the query result?

Comment: YEs - you can see the actual page here - http://www.musicpax.com/_PUBLIC/index_mpx.php?t=mpxmusic&p=0&o=p

Comment: Note each row is in proper order but not each item in that row... It looks as if it sorts secondarily by TITLE, but that is not in the Query?

Comment: So it appears the ITEMS in the ROW are ASC but the ROWS are DESC?

Answer (score 0):

The PROBLEM was actually in the CSS - the "class="col-sm-3" was set to float-right, therefore reversing the flow of the output. Sorry for the confusion, as the CSS was not present.

This is very interesting that the style dictated the output flow - hmmm.

Thank you for your help Naishant.

Comment: oh..! `col-sm-3` which divided the screen and messed up the output